# custom rake task for precompile assets locally rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I need precompile assets on my local machine and after make deploy with capistrano with assets precompiled.

I have added to `development.rb`:

```
config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"
```

also, I have added to `application.rb`

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Instead execute `rake assets:precompile` manually, I want make this process from capistrano file automated, clean assets, upload...etc. I have tried with this custom task

```
namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
        run_locally "rsync -zvrh --progress -e 'ssh -i #{ssh_options[:keys][0]}' public/assets #{user}{server}:#{shared_path}"
        puts "cleaning up locally compiled assets"
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:clean"
      else
        puts "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
```

But I get a error:

```
/config/deploy.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in load': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I precompile assets on local and after upload with capistrano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed:

This is my custom task is working fine:

```
 namespace :assets do
    task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do
      from = source.next_revision(current_revision)
      if capture("cd #{latest_release} && #{source.local.log(from)} vendor/assets/ app/assets/ | wc -l").to_i > 0
        run_locally("rm -rf public/assets/*") 
        run_locally "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
        find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
         run_locally "rsync -vr --exclude='.DS_Store' public/assets #{user}@#{server.host}:#{shared_path}/"
        end
      else
        puts.info "Skipping asset pre-compilation because there were no asset changes"
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `logger.info` in the `else` block is the issue.

If you *need* a logger in Capistrano for other reasons, you may need to initialize it manually because your not actually running in the server.  But it might be easier to just print to the console (as you're doing with your other messages above

Replace

```
logger.info "Skipping ..."
```

with

```
puts "Skipping ..."
```

Comment: Thank you but I have edited the question, the error is different is other error. Thank you!

Comment: can you give a bit more context around the error?  clearly your deploy.rb script is trying to access something that's not there (like maybe an environment hash?)  what does your deploy script look like around lie 73 where the error is happening?

Comment: I have fixed the error. The fix is on the next reply. Thank you very much!